# Beta-diversity for data with zeros

Tags: statistics, biostatistics, biodiversity, species-distribution

**Background**
I am looking into enterotyping the gut microbiome data, obtained by shotgun sequencing. This essentially means performing the Principal Coordinates Analysis (PCoA/NMDS) of the beta-diversity matrix (distance matrix), based on the abundance table of species/gene-counts for all possible species/genes in all samples: for sample $i$ the counts of species/genes are $\mathbf{x}_i=(x_{i1}, x_{i2},...,x_{im})$. Such a table necessarily contains many zeros, whenever a species/gene is not present in a sample. Some of the possible beta-diversity measures are listed in table 1 of [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7891732/pdf/pone.0246893.pdf).

**Problem**
Statistically speaking, such data are considered to be an example of *compositional data*, i.e., the meaningful information is contained only in the ratios of the counts, which makes log-based distances the most suitable ones. These are used in many statistical methods (see, e.g., [here](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:abtmartins:a_concise_guide_to_compositional_data_analysis.pdf)). However, the log-transofmation is meaningful only when all the entries in the count table are strictly positive $x_{ik}>0$. One thus faces a problem of dealing with zero entries.

**Possible solutions**

- Using metrics not sensitive to zero entries (excluding *alr*, *ilr* and other similar log-transformations, highly recommended by statisticians - this limits the choice of statistical methods)
- Imputation of zeros: this requires a principled/biologically-sound way of imputing the zeros, since the results may be potentially very sensitive to this choice.

**Question**
What are the commonly used imputation methods? What is their advantages/disadvantages and justification for their use?

**Some references**

- [Here is a statisticians' view on imputation in compositional data](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:abtmartins:dealingwithzerosandmissingvalues.pdf): the methodology may get rather involved, but does not have any specific biological basis.

Comment: An appropriate way to handle this is with a so-called zero-inflated model: https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/articles/brms_families.html#zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models-1.

Comment: I'll often use the pseudocount method for exploratory analyses. Basically just apply a pseudocount of 1 to every count in the table (since Log(1) = 0), so the action you actually end up performing is Log(x+1).

Comment: @MikeyC Pseudocount is what I meant by "imputation of zeros": it is certainly a good method when one is interested only in the most abundant species (those that have counts), but I see how it may create problems when detecting low abandance species is important.

Comment: @vkehayas if I understand correctly, zero inflation corrects for undersampled species - one will still have actual zeros in the count table?

Comment: Correct, you still keep them in the sample. The model estimates parameter values for a separate process leading to ratios at zero and parameter values for a separate process leading to values $\in (0, 1)$. A great introduction to similar models can be found in McElreath's Statistical Rethinking book ([slides](https://github.com/rmcelreath/statrethinking_winter2019), [lecture 13](https://youtu.be/p7g-CgGCS34)).

Comment: To be honest I feel like this question would be better on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Comment: I'll also point out that most of the suggestions here focus on what to do about zeros, but don't consider compositionality. You'd ideally want a solution that considered (1) presence of zeros (via inflation or just low means), (2) discrete nature of data (i.e., potentially higher sampling variance at low densities) and (3) compositionality. [This example](https://microbiome.github.io/OMA/community-typing.html) uses Dirichlet-multinomial mixtures, but then reverts to Bray-Curtis-based PCoA for ordination.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix since it accounts for abundances and can handle the so called double zero problem. I'm on my commute now and so must return to this for a complete answer later

Comment: I am looking forward to more details!

Comment: @Roger I'm not trying to ignore you. Started teaching summer classes + summer research students, so I've gotten a bit tied up. I'll get back to this soon.